# Filter out individuals who developed diseases in a certain sequence

Tags: r

I have a data frame - each individual has multiple visits. I want to filter out patients who had disease 2 after disease 1. Sometimes a patient can have disease 3 between 1 and 2, and they should be included too. In this case, I would pick out ID 2 & 4 & 6.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6)
Visit <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)
Disease <- c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2)
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, Disease)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  filter(Disease == 1 & lead(Disease) == 2, .by = ID) |> 
  pull(ID)
```

Result:

```
[1] 2 4
```

**Edit:**

The original question was extended such that cases with disease sequence (1, 3, 2) shall also be included:

```
df |>
  filter(Disease == 1 &
           (lead(Disease) == 2 |
              (lead(Disease) == 3 & lead(Disease, n = 2) == 2)), .by = ID) |>
  pull(ID)
```

Result:

```
[1] 2 4 6
```

**Edit 2:**

OP stated in the comments that every sequence (1, 3, 3, 3, ..., 3, 3, 2) shall be allowed, this could be solved like this:

```
library(stringr)

df |>
  filter(str_detect(str_c(Disease, collapse = ""), "12|13+2$"), .by = ID) |> 
  distinct(ID)
```

Result:

```
  ID
1  2
2  4
3  6
```

Comment: Thank you ! This is great! What if a patient developed disease 3 between 1 and 2 and I want to include them too? For example, their diseases status is (1, 3, 2)

Comment: Additionally: If you have a question with three answers, one of them accepted, it's not the way to go to unaccept one answer and edit the question with additional requirements such that all already given answers are not complete anymore.

Comment: The answer is updated now.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't convey what I wanted in the original question very well and the answer didn't result in what I wanted. I feel like it's still not doing what I want, some patients could be (1,3,3,2) or (1,3,3,3,2), etc and I want to include them too.

Comment: Okay, I also include the cases (1, 3, 3, ..., 3, 3, 2) in Edit 2 above, please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

this is deceptively tricky but i used `dplyr` to solve this. first filter for patients who had `disease` 1 and 2 and then filter for those who had `disease` 1 first then `disease` 2

```r
library(dplyr)

ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5)
Visit <- c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2)
Disease <- c(2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1)
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, Disease)

# Filter patients who had both diseases 1 and 2
patients_both_diseases <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(any(Disease == 1) & any(Disease == 2))

# Filter patients where disease 2 occurred after disease 1
final_df <- patients_both_diseases %>%
  filter(first(which(Disease == 1)) < first(which(Disease == 2))) %>%
  distinct(ID)

final_df
```

if you want to print the entire table you can remove the `distinct(ID)` bit.

Comment: What if a patient's disease is (2,1,2) then they won't be included

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df,Disease %in% c(1,2)) %>% filter(max(diff(Disease))>0, .by=ID)
```

Output:

```
  ID Visit Disease
1  2     1       1
2  2     2       2
3  2     3       1
4  4     1       2
5  4     2       1
6  4     3       2
7  6     1       1
8  6     3       2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `paste` strings out of the diseases, e.g. `'121'` for patient 2. Then `grepl` in a temporary `.k` column for regex patterns `12|132` and `subset`. Use `ave` to do group by `ID`.

```
> df |> 
+   transform(.k=ave(Disease, ID, FUN=\(x) grepl('12|132', paste(x, collapse='')))) |> 
+   subset(.k == 1, select=-.k)
   ID Visit Disease
3   2     1       1
4   2     2       2
5   2     3       1
9   4     1       2
10  4     2       1
11  4     3       2
14  6     1       1
15  6     2       3
16  6     3       2
```

This can easily be extended to other cases such as `'32'` for developed disease 2 after 3, or `'^1+$'` for only disease 1, or `'^2'` for first developed disease 2, or `'^[^13]*$'` for did NOT develop disease 1 or 3 etc.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), Visit = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), Disease = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16"))
```